# Hot to change standard input fields to an image?

Tags: html, css

Hot to change standard input fields to an image?

```
<input class="FeedBack" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><br>
<input class="FeedBack" type="email" placeholder="mail@mail.ru"><br>
<textarea class="FeedBack" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5fnvt1mu/

I want to use this image instead of standart input field
https://ibb.co/3dwx295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use CSS to style the input field.

```
.FeedBack {
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 450px;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightblue; /*change to whatever colour you want */
    color: lightgray; /*change to whatever colour you want */ 
}
```

This one looks to be:

```css
.FeedBack {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  border: 1px solid lightblue; /*change to whatever colour you want */
  color: lightgray; /*change to whatever colour you want */ 
}
```

```html
<input class="FeedBack" type="text" placeholder="Full name"><br>
<input class="FeedBack" type="email" placeholder="mail@mail.ru"><br>
<textarea class="FeedBack" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
```